# Error while running PIP command "no module packaging exists"

Tags: python-2.7

I have tried many approaches in resolving this issue but still cannot resolve it can someone please help me.

when I try to run the `pip` to install any new package it is ending in error with the message `no module named packaging.version`. This is happening in the `__init__.py` file where there are import command `import packaging.version`.

I tried to install the packaging package by using the command `pip install packaging` even that ended in failure with the same error.

Then I tried to install this package using the apt-get command

> `sudo apt-get install python-packaging` but it ended saying `could not find the package`.

Finally I tried to update the `setuptools` package to version `33.1.1` as a part of the previous solutions approaches, but can't do it with pip(same issue as above) so I used the apt-get command

> `sudo apt-get install setuptools=33.1.1` but it is saying `no package with this version found error`.

I am out of ideas can someone please help. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your version of pip is obsolete. Try running `pip install --upgrade pip`.

If you cant do it (still the same error), I'd suggest to reinstall pip.
You can do it with `get-pip.py` file. Here you can find a quick guide: [Installing pip setuptools and wheel](https://packaging.python.org/installing/#install-pip-setuptools-and-wheel).

You may also be able to reinstall it with `python -m pip install -U pip`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes it worked. Thanks for time and solution